# why isn't gcc passing macro value from the command line?

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to pass the value of a C macro to the preprocessor with the -Dmacro=value option of gcc. However, it doesn't do what i expect. This is the basics of my code:

```
#define T0 0
#define T1 0
#define T2 0
#define T3 0

int main(){

    int f[9];

    start(f[T0], f[T1], f[T2], f[T3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Running `gcc -DT3=1 -E` shows the preprocessor does not replace the original value of T3. What am i missing, and how can the value be passed properly?

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself, and was a little bit surprised b/c I always thought that the command line definition should override the inline definition. I vaguely remember that the Microsoft compiler does that, but unfortunately, I don't have access to one for some time. I anyone with MSVC can test that and post the info, that will be nice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Afaik that switch will define a macro, but your code then overrides it back to 0. Remove that define from your code or surround it with ifdef and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef T3
   #define T3 0
#endif
```

The above snippet will make sure the value you pass will be reflected.